# get a key value from an array of objects in lodash

Tags: angular, typescript

I get it to work in the snippet but not in my typescript code. I get

> property colorId and sizeId does not exist on type {}

```js
 const ids = [
        {
            "skuId": 693194,
            "sizeId": "12M",
            "colorId": "ROSE"
        },
        {
            "skuId": 693195,
            "sizeId": "14M",
            "colorId": "ROSE"
        },
        {
            "skuId": 973804,
            "sizeId": "6M",
            "colorId": "GREEN"
        }
     ]
     
     const sku = _.result(_.find(ids, function(sku) {
                  return sku.colorId === 'ROSE' && 
                    sku.sizeId === '14M';
                                    }), 'skuId');
                                    
                                    console.log(sku);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi .. if you're using typescript and angular maybe try with:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by casting ids to Array

```
_.result(_.find(<Array<any>>ids, function(sku) {
              return sku.colorId === 'ROSE' && 
                sku.sizeId === '14M';
                                }), 'skuId');

                                console.log(sku);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using typescript and angular maybe try with:

```
let myids= ids.filter(sku => sku.color === 'ROSE' && 
                    sku.sizeId === '14M'; ).map(yy=>yy.skuId);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I cast to Array and it seems to work <Array<any>>ids

Comment: if you want you can cast also as string like let myids= ids.filter(sku => sku.color === 'ROSE' && 
                    sku.sizeId === '14M'; ).map(yy=>yy.skuId) as Array<string>;